# Как отменить выполнение $.click для родителей элемента?

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Задача: получать информацию об любом элементе, на который произошел клик мышкой.

Проблема: при клике происходит вызов события (получения информации) для всех объектов-родителей.

Пример:

```
<div>text1<section>text2</section></div>

$(function(){
  $('body *').click(function(){
    alert('1');
  });
});
```

При клике на text2 вызовется два алерта. Как сделать, чтобы вызывался один? Заранее скажу, что мне нужен вызов алерта на ЛЮБОЙ элемент на странице.

Comment: Ты лучший!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```